# Can I reliably use the value os.version to determine the Linux distro?

Tags: java, linux, parsing

I'm parsing customer logs, I need to want to figure out which distro they are running. I can't run commands on their systems, all I have is the logs.

The property os.name always returns, Linux, but the os.version returns what appears to be the kernel version? For instance, 2.6.9-42.0.3.ELsmp or 2.6.5-7.283-smp.

After some google is appears that the last characters of the os.version can be mapped to a distro.

Values ending in, ELsmp or el, map to Redhat, just plain smp maps to SUSE.

Is that true or I'm just engaging in wishfully thinking?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by this question.  Why do you "need" to know this?  Why can't your application run some external command to find out the version?  Why can't you just ask the customer?

Comment: That's a good question, I have a lot of existing data that does not contain an obvious way to determine the disto. For instance, uname, on SUSE, the string does not contain any obvious reference to SUSE, just SMP. Maybe another command is available but that leads to forking an external command, which can lead to other issues, pathing and permissions. If I can figure out the disto from a common java vm property, my issue becomes much simpler. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true as long as they use distro-specific kernels - vanilla kernels with distro-specific patches applied.
But they might also use entirely different or custom kernels, maybe even a vanilla kernel. And I'm not sure what will happen if it is a virtual machine. Those kernels might end in -xen or -openvz or something similar.
Different distros may also use the same kernel, so that makes it even harder again.

Comment: Yes, virtual slices are going to be a headache, but I don't need complete mapping, for those special cases, we'll ask the customer directly and store the answer in our config database.

Answer (score 0):

If the distro vendor applies their own patches to the kernel, they usually add a tag to the version number to indicate that it's a custom version of the kernel.  If they just use the stock kernel as written by Linus and friends, then there often won't be a tag.

The tag may even be different between distros by the same vendor, that would otherwise be compatible.  Or it may be the same for different distros.  (Last i saw, Fedora kernels didn't have the "EL" or "el" tags.  CentOS kernels, however, have the same tags as RHEL.)  Or, for some distros, it may not be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get info for the major distributions, true. But it won't be possible to guess it for 100% of your logs.

FYI: search `generic` or `generic-pae` for Ubuntu, but you'll miss some other. Debian don't have specific endings apart from `-686` and `-amd64`, but it must be the case for many other distributions.

Comment: At this time, we only support Redhat and SUSE, but thanks for the heads up.